# LINQ .Count() not defined for int

Tags: linq

I have the below LINQ statement, and get the error " 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found ( are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?) "

```
var queryFuture = from pqv in context.OrderPrintQueue_View
                          join od in context.Order_Details on pqv.confirmId equals od.ConfirmId
                          join pp in context.Product_Price on od.priceId equals pp.priceId
                          join p in context.Products on pp.productId equals p.ProductID
                          select new { p.stationId, inProc = 0, OrderLinesCount = od.recId.Count() };
```

**od.recId.Count()** is the portion that is returning an error. I'm very new to LINQ (have been using it for about 2 days) and am a novice programmer. The answers I have found all say to include the system.core assembly reference, and of course, the System.Linq  using. I have all of those so I'm not sure what the deal is. I am using WPF with .NET 4, EF, and  RIA services and the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recID` is of type `int`, not `IEnumerable<?>`. `Count()` is only defined on `IEnumerable<?>`. You will ned a `group by` statement:

```
var queryFuture = from pqv in context.OrderPrintQueue_View
                          join od in context.Order_Details on pqv.confirmId equals od.ConfirmId
                          join pp in context.Product_Price on od.priceId equals pp.priceId
                          join p in context.Products on pp.productId equals p.ProductID
                          group od by od.recId into orders
                          select new { p.stationId, inProc = 0, OrderLinesCount = orders.Count() };
```

Note: I'm not sure of this combination of `group by` and `join` will work out, as I usually only use the method chains. You might have to adjust on the operators, however you'll need a `group by` in any case.

Comment: This looks like what I am trying to get to, however; p is highlighted and says : The name 'p' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I'm terrible sorry, I just can't wrap my head around it without a compiler; I can supply you with a link though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx. This should help you, it is similar to your problem.

Comment: Although, I was not able to do what I wanted with just one LINQ statement ( I think it is possible ) it was helpful to know that I needed to, at some point, group the items.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to get the count for an integer? You are probably getting a single value back, not a collection, which it seems is what you are expecting.